# Laravel whereHas only bring back models that match criteria

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working in a Laravel 10 project and need to just return tier's where each tier's options matches some criteria. Right now I need to do it based on a column called `type`. For reference, I only have 2 entries in my table out of around 700 that should match "private", but when I use a `whereHas` and set the `where` to pull back records that match private, I get everything returned.

If I change "private" to something that doesn't exist, I get nothing.

What am I missing here to just return models that match a set of criteria and then don't load tier options and tiers where options don't match?

```php
$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers.options'
])->whereHas('tiers.options', function ($query) {
    $query->where([
        ['type', 'private']
    ]);
})->get();
```

Here's an example of what I mean by `options` being returned with an empty array:

```
{
    "model": null,
    "metadata": {
        "model_count": 1,
        "model_data": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 1,
                "company_id": 1,
                "name": "FakeBuyer",
                "description": "A collection of dummy and faker buyer tiers.",
                "is_default": false,
                "is_enabled": true,
                "last_used_at": "2023-04-18T09:59:50.000000Z",
                "created_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:04.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-04-18T09:59:51.000000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "is_deleting": false,
                "tiers": [
                    {
                        "id": 69,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "buyer_id": 3,
                        "country_id": 1,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "name": "Fake-accept 62",
                        "description": "Fake accept with delay",
                        "processing_class": "FakeBuyer",
                        "is_default": false,
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "last_used_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:04.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:04.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "options": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 70,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "buyer_id": 3,
                        "country_id": 1,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "name": "Fake-accept 63",
                        "description": "Fake accept with delay",
                        "processing_class": "FakeBuyer",
                        "is_default": false,
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "last_used_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "id": 764,
                                "user_id": 1,
                                "company_id": 1,
                                "buyer_tier_id": 70,
                                "name": "min_price",
                                "value": 2.5,
                                "description": null,
                                "cast": "float",
                                "type": "private",
                                "is_enabled": true,
                                "created_at": "2023-04-17T15:13:16.000000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2023-04-17T15:13:16.000000Z",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "type_formatted": "Private",
                                "is_deleting": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 71,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "buyer_id": 3,
                        "country_id": 1,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "name": "Fake-accept 64",
                        "description": "Fake accept with delay",
                        "processing_class": "FakeBuyer",
                        "is_default": false,
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "last_used_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "id": 765,
                                "user_id": 1,
                                "company_id": 1,
                                "buyer_tier_id": 71,
                                "name": "min_price",
                                "value": 5,
                                "description": null,
                                "cast": "float",
                                "type": "private",
                                "is_enabled": true,
                                "created_at": "2023-04-18T10:33:04.000000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2023-04-18T10:33:04.000000Z",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "type_formatted": "Private",
                                "is_deleting": false
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 72,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "buyer_id": 3,
                        "country_id": 1,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "name": "Fake-accept 65",
                        "description": "Fake accept with delay",
                        "processing_class": "FakeBuyer",
                        "is_default": false,
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "last_used_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-04-17T13:41:05.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "options": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You see that the buyer tier "Fake-accept 62" has been retrieved despite it having no options. For the ones that are retrieved, it should match the type of private.

Here's loads of attempts I've done:

```php
$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers.options'
])->whereHas('tiers.options', function ($query) {
    $query->where([
        ['type', 'private']
    ]);
})->get();

$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers.options'
])->withWhereHas('tiers.options', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'private');
})->get();

$buyers = Buyer::with('tiers.options', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'private')
})->get();

$buyers = Buyer::withWhereHas('tiers.options', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'private');
})->get();
```

They all continue to bring back tiers with no options despite the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query means you get buyers who have the type of tiers.options = private and get all tiers.options of those buyers

If you want to get buyers who have the type of tiers.options = private and also just get tiers.options that has type = private, you use withWhereHas:

```
$buyers = Buyer::withWhereHas('tiers', function($query) {
   $query->withWhereHas('options', function ($query) {
      $query->where([
         ['type', 'private']
      ]);
   });
})->get();
```

Comment: This still returns buyers with tiers that contain an empty `options` array. I only want to return buyers with tiers where the tier options match the where clause and nothing else.

Comment: Can you show your new code and clear more your needs? dd($buyers) and mark the right things and the wrong things

Comment: I've updated my description with returned data and more attempts. That should give more context. I'm getting buyer tiers returned even though options is empty. I don't want this. I only want tiers that have options and where the options match my where clause.

Comment: I'm trying to combine a `with()` and `withWhereHas` but I'm not getting any query results shown for the `with`? Why could this be? For example, before running `withWhereHas` I'm doing: `Buyer::with(['tiers' => function ($query) { ... }])->withWhereHas()`

Comment: If you put withWhereHas('tiers') after with('tiers'), it will use withWhereHas('tiers') instead. WithWhereHas() = with() + whereHas()

Answer (score -1):

try to add `tiers` to with and then call the nested relation :

```
$buyers = Buyer::with([
    'tiers','tiers.options'
])
```

Comment: Similar to the point above. I'm still getting loads of tiers where `options` is an empty array. What's going on here?

Comment: `::with('tiers.options')` and `::with(['tiers', 'tiers.options'])` are equivalent. If you use `nested.relationship`, both `nested` and `relationship` are included, so there's no need to redundantly specify both.